# How to debug a python - c++ program

Tags: python, c++, debugging

I got a quite complex distributed programming framework where there are:

1. a Controller, `BC`, written in Python as a `twisted` plugin, which is running on some machine;
2. *N* Daemons, `BM`, written in Python but wrapping a C++ core as a shared library, in the following way:

`import imp
 handle = imp.load_dynamic('mylib', '../libmy.so')`

Then each `BM` talks to the `BC` via a `jsonrpc` interaction, but we don't care about this.

What I would do is to debug, possibly in a *step into*/*step over*/*step debug* fashion but not limited to, a `BM` process, which at the front-end appears as a homogeneous stream of characters in a single terminal.

I'm **strongly interested into the C++ part**, considering the Python code almost final to release and working well.

Due to this language mixture I'm a bit confused about what type of tool may be useful.

Comment: No they can't. Daemons are *actually* Python code which calls few but essential APIs from C++ library mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that nuance; apologies.

Comment: Well in facts I could build a C++ outer executable representing the work done by Python daemon; but the answer from WakkaDojo reduces the problem to what we're talking about :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gdb on any C/C++ extensions loaded through Python. The way this is done is:

```
(gdb) target exec python
(gdb) run
 >>> import your_extension as ye
 >>> ye.do_something ()
 >>> # do your python here
 >>> # or just run your python script from here
(gdb) do debugging stuff
```

You can also add breakpoints/do full C/C++ debugging via gdb. Tip from [boost::python docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#debugging)